# Qwerty checker index out of range

Tags: python, array

```
passArray = ['s','d','f','r']

qwertyLine=["QWE","WER","ERT","RTY","TYU","YUI","UIO","IOP","ASD","SDF","DFG","FGH","GHJ","HJK","JKL","ZXC","XCV","CVB","VBN","BNM"]

PasswordScore = 0

NumQwerty = 0

for x in range(0,len(passArray)-1):

    qwertyCheck = passArray[x] + passArray[x+1] + passArray[x+2]
    check = qwertyCheck.upper()
    if check in qwertyLine:
        NumQwerty = NumQwerty + 1

QwertyDeduction = NumQwerty * 5

PasswordScore = PasswordScore - QwertyDeduction

print(PasswordScore)
```

I'm trying to check for qwerty characters together in a list and when I run the following code I get the index out of range error but not sure why.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. We're a community for reviewing *working* code. Thus your question is off-topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of 1, subtract 2 from `len(passArray)`.

**Edit**:
With the first iteration, `check` is set to 'SDF'.
With the second, `check` is set to 'DFR'.
On the third iteration, with the `range` being (0, 3), you are going past the end of the list and so you're getting `IndexError: list index out of range`.

However, if you subtract 2 from the length, you'll have a `range(0, 2)` and with this the loop iterates over the list twice so first you have `check = 'SDF'`, then `check = 'DFR'` and the loop ends here.

Comment: Code Review is for reviewing working code, so the question is to be closed. Additionally, your answer doesn't consist of a review - it's just a fix without explanation.

Comment: Brilliant this solved the issue but to be honest I'm not sure I understand why? If you could explain I will be forever in your debt :)

Comment: @Leeeroyb, please see my edit.

Comment: @Pimgd, sorry I thought I was on SO.

Comment: @srig So would i be right in my thinking of this would not work if I was to add more characters to my list passArray?

Comment: @Leeeroyb, add more characters, it still works. If you've any more questions with code not working, please post them at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).